# SSIS with CozyRoc adapter creating duplicate records in Dynamics CRM

Tags: ssis, microsoft-dynamics

It is a SSIS Package to create records in Dynamics CRM 2015 on-premise from a SQL Table. We are using CozyRoc adapter for Dynamics CRM Destination. Batch size to create records in CRM is 100. Intermittently it is creating duplicate records in CRM. The same batch records are getting created more than one time. If the batch size is 100, then sometimes the same 100 records are created one more time resulting in 200 records by duplicating each one of the 100 records one more time. If I change the batch size to 50, then the some of the 50 records in the the same batch are created one more time. The same issue happens for Update also. Sometimes the same batch keeps on being re-created in CRM continuously. No error was recorded in CRM during this duplicate creation.

When I googled it, somebody suggested as if the SQL Query used in the source component having "no lock" key, then the duplication can happen rarely. But in our case, we are not using "no lock" keyword for the source component SQL Query.

Please let me know if anybody else has faced this kind of issue and solved it successfully.

SQL Server 2012 (11.0.6020.0)
Dynamics CRM 2015 On premise (7.0.1.144)
SSIS Package created by Visual Studio 2010 Shell (10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel)
CozyRoc Adapter (v1.6 SR3)